# How are audits created for review queues? (Complaint about one specific case)

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I'm currently working on the reviews of the Re-open cases.

I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29531029).

The question basically says:

> I have an error with some code, and here is the code.

The question was closed saying that more explanation and/or clarity was needed.

The question has been modified into:

> I have an error with some code, here is the code and here is the error message.

I thought: indeed some relevant information has been added, so now the question might be re-opened.

I got as a result: Stop! Look and Listen. This was an audit, ...

I do understand audits, showing complete nonsense or even abusive language, but this is really stretching: it means people need to be experts in artificial intelligence (the subject of this question) just to be able to judge such questions. Please don't go that far.

Comment: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/11682469)

Comment: I'm skipping more than 70% of the cases, but this one really seemed a "slam dunk" good candidate for re-opening, hence this complaint.

Comment: The question has been deleted though, we non-10k cannot see it... possibly the question was deemed not suitable on SO for other reasons, regardless of the edit.

Comment: @AndrewT.: that's exactly my point: if the judgement would have been "Not applicable for SO", even adding some error message would not convince me to ask for re-opening (as proposed by Jeanne, I would have skipped it). Even then, I could very well understand a judgment being wrong, but not the usage of such a case for auditing purposes.

Comment: For <10k users: [the edit](https://i.imgur.com/P3EY0tg.png), [the full question](https://i.imgur.com/3tBxkHy.png), [the timeline](https://i.imgur.com/h0yrZGp.png). It seems that the question got 3 downvotes, it was later updated but was cleaned up by Roomba before anybody voted on the reopen task. IMO, the audit is bad. The question *looks* reopenable but I'm not an expert. Nobody really voted "keep closed", so I don't think it's correct for the system to conclude that it *should* be kept closed.

Comment: I have only limited knowledge about the technology, but question seems to be asking which additional pre-processing step to add to an image detection problem without stating what should be detected in which way and without showing sample input.

Comment: @Dominique - You should be opening up the question, of a review candidate, to verify the question still exists.  You failed the audit because you indicated a question that had already been deleted should be reopened.

Comment: @SecurityHound: that's my point: somebody writes a question, a second person mentions that there should be more information, again a person decides to delete the question, again another person decides to turn this question into an audit, I think the second person is correct, and I get punished by the fourth person. My point is that this question never should have been used as an audit.

Comment: @SecurityHound I disagree. Audits are not there to be checked if they are audits. The workflow you suggest is "For each review task, see if it's an audit - if it is, act according as its current state. If it's not, *then* act* on the information provided". However, you should not fail an audit based on the information provided. *Could* have OP checked the current state of the question? Yes. *Should* they have checked the current state of the question? No. It should never be a requirement to do that. It defeats the purpose of having audits if they are just checking if you know about audits.

Comment: FWIW, the question seems not even to have valid syntax. The error message is pretty pointless without a traceback or MCVE. Basically the question changed from "I got an error and ain't telling how", to "I got a useless error and ain't telling how".

Comment: "How are audits created for review queues?" -> automatic. Hence their quality is not guaranteed and there is nobody to blame for it.

Comment: The timing of the deletion might make this a bad audit but I don't think the edit does. If the edit doesn't actually make a question clear and it got a unanimous Leave Closed review, that should be fair game for the system to use for an audit.

Comment: I would consider a feature request that said that questions deleted while they had a pending Reopen Review task shouldn't be eligible for audits. The logic behind picking a post for an audit is "Everyone strongly agreed about the quality of this post" which arguably isn't true if no one (or not enough people) voted on the reopen task.

Comment: @Gimby: audits are created automatically? That's rather dangerous, as mentioned in the edit of my question.

Comment: I fell into one again, I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Please don't vote to open questions if you are not an expert in subject. The questions in general should only be reopened if they are answerable (e.g. if someone in comments "guessed" the root issue right and OP confirmed, from this moment the answer can be posted). You can't reliably judge what piece is missing unless you are an expert. E.g. WPF questions are almost always require xaml, you can't know this, so please hit the "Skip". As a `C++` expert you can do a good job by focusing on judging C++ questions.

Comment: @Sinatr: I agree, hence this other question I've asked about this subject (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410614/parametrisation-of-sorting-of-review-queues), I just adopted the attitude "Why complain about a situation which happened in the past if you can propose to avoid it in future?".

Comment: ... and another one, this time for the "Close votes".

Answer (score 8):

This seems like a perfectly good audit candidate to me.

---

The most glaring issue is that the question does not include syntactically valid code. The edit did not change that in the slightest.
If you have ever read an internet rant for or against Python, this issue should frankly be obvious. Simply put, if you are that unfamiliar with the topic of the review then Skip it.

---

Other issues of the edited question:

- The code uses local paths. It cannot be a MCVE.
- The added error is next to useless without a traceback.

Comment: Plus that question fails the basic help vampire sniff test: it contains the dreaded "help please" (or "please help") phrase that they love to use when they're just vomiting code at Stack Overflow and expecting us to fix it for them.

Comment: Since when do **questions** need syntactically valid code? If the problem is a syntax error then an answer could point that out and how to fix it.

Comment: @user000001 Questions need code *for the debugging problem they are asking about*. The question was not asking about a syntax error.