# Parametrisation of sorting of review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I'm currently working on some review queues, and I've stumbled upon some questions I voted to re-open, although they have been marked as audits, which increases the risk of being banned from reviewing.

I have created [a question concerning this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410587), and the last comment I got (from [Sinatr](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr)) was:

> Please don't vote to open questions if you are not an expert in subject. Period.

Although this appears quite harsh (and it's probably meant that way) this comment contains a valuable point, and I would like to elaborate this:

Currently the review queues don't care about the tags one is watching, and therefore I get quite some review tasks about unknown technology (which I usually skip), and as a result when I do get a review task concerning a technology I know a bit about, I won't skip and try to handle it, which sometimes throws me into the audit pit.

Therefore I would like to use the "watched tags" as an input for the review queue tasks, so that the question I (firstly) get, are indeed review queues about technologies I'm familiar with. Other technologies can be shown afterwards.

So I'm not asking NOT to show unfamiliar technologies, I just ask to show familiar technologies (watched tags) FIRST.

Is this a valid proposal?

**Edit after new testing**

I am now using the filter, but altough I've set the tags [Excel], [C++] and [C#], I still get thrown into "Audits" like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/29553378).

Comment: The reopen and the close vote review queue already allow you to filter by tag. Just click on the filter button at the top and add tags. Is you proposal just to initially set the filter to your watched tags?

Comment: Relevant https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575

Comment: @gnat that feature got removed from all sites.

Answer (score 6):

Better just to use filters.

There are enough posts in the queue that is equivalent to "sorting", particularly in the close/reopen queues, where subject expertise tends to be more relevant (even more so in the "Reopen" queue).

If you "sorted" as you propose, you'll still spend all your review actions for a day on "your" tags before ever reaching a post about a tag you know nothing about. You would  accomplish the same end result using the already existing filter feature:

[image]

Comment: Oh...!, yep indeed...!, and that works also for the 'First Posts' Queue (I only have 500+_Rep)...! But this Func could be mentioned in the Quick Help (Popup) for the Queue (and all Queues actually I would think), or at least on the Page for the Queue in the [Help Center] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-posts)... But nope, that's not mentioned/explained anywhere...

Comment: ["the problem \[with filters\] is that it is poorly advertised and its usage is low by new reviewers (and sometimes old ones). \[...\] Also, it has the inconvenience that it is static, and needs manual intervention to modify it."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254145/213575)