# Why is this typo question a post in review?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, specific-audit, first-questions

I just encountered [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30330735).

I immediately identified it as a review audit, and confirmed it by going to the question. But, as I didn't understand why it was removed, I chose "*Share feedback*".

The question has been closed for being a result of a typo. A reason that I didn't see, because I don't try to answer questions that I'm reviewing.

For me, the question seems clear: Code, explanation of the problem and the expected result. Other questions like this on Meta Stack Overflow have answers which suggest to skip them, e.g., [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412661/10952503). But if I hadn't checked the age of the post, I would have failed the audit by clicking "Looks OK".

Should typo questions be review audits?

A lot of typo questions also do not have enough details and are closed as *need more details*, so I think it's not a good reason to use them as audits.

I would like to add that I encountered [a new audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30751207) which is a typo review, and which seems to be good by itself.

Comment: The answer is the same as always, audits are automatically chosen based on certain heuristics like whether they're closed and their score. Potentially more helpful for you would be a feature request for typo questions not to be used as audits.

Comment: Since review audits are not only used on SO but also on other SE sites, and that off-topic reasons are customizable per-site, I don't think the logic to choose review audits cares about the specific close reason...

Comment: @Nick yes, maybe. I just would to start with this post and maybe we will convert it into bug question.

Comment: @AndrewT. Oh, that's a good point. I think this is a good way to explain why it's included.

Comment: People here seem to imply that if a question is said to be _caused by typos_, it undoubtedly were a _typo question_; that's all too often not true.

Comment: "A lot of typo questions also do not have enough details and are closed as need more details, so I think it's not a good reason to use them as audits." Doesn't that mean that typo questions cannot be consistently filtered out, and we will get typo questions anyway?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something or should the question be closed with a different reason or maybe not closed at all? After all, it's not a typo, and it is reproducible: It just can't be answer with anything but "no, this is not possible". So the question is actually wrongly closed IMO. (which ofcourse makes a confusing audit)

Comment: @MegaIng it's closed for typo because we write "GET" instead of "POST". But yes, the "typo" closed reason can be disputed too

Comment: @Nick That's actually a very good idea.

Comment: @Elikill58 it seems however that the OP actually wanted to have a GET, he even explicitly mentions it in the text, although it’s unclear how he wanted to receive the CSRF token. It thus remains unanswerable as such.

Comment: The question should absolutely be closed. Just as a duplicate of one of the hundreds of "I used GET when I should have used POST" questions we have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Typo questions as review audits *generally* make sense, under two conditions:

**1. The listed reason that it is flagged/voted for closure indicates that it is thought to be a typo**

[image]

The close vote queue reviews questions that are thought to be typos.  Reviewers should be reading the reasons for closure at the top of the review page and using them to guide their review.  If they are able to determine whether or not the cause is in fact a typo, they should vote to Close or Leave Open.  Otherwise, they should Skip.

I don't know offhand if this is how such an audit is actually shown.  If it's not, that should be considered a bug.  It's not reasonable to expect typos to be identified by reviewers without a hint.

**2. The question is *actually caused by a typo***

That's the problem here: it's *not a typo*.  The question is quite clear that the asker wants the form to be sent over GET.  They didn't just accidentally write POST instead of GET (that'd be a typo).  The fact that you can't have parameters outside of the URL in a GET form is an *answer to the question*, not a reason for closing it.  It's caused by a misunderstanding of what's possible.  Thus, this is a bad audit, because the question should not have been closed for this reason, and in fact maybe shouldn't have been closed at all (unless it's a duplicate).

Comment: Too much emphasis is placed on the word "typo" in this close reason. Everyone starts sounding [like Arnold in Kindergarten Cop](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=it%27s+not+a+tumor&view=detail&mid=9284B3CE6BE339F098C79284B3CE6BE339F098C7&FORM=VIRE) "It's not a typo". In any case, the close reason does not match, but what you consider a parenthetical, I consider a main point; close it as a duplicate of the many, many other questions that have been asked about why hidden field data are exposed in the URL when GET is used instead of POST. The question *definitely should have been closed*.

Comment: "you can't have parameters outside of the URL in a GET form" what's funny is HTTP actually allows it but the browser won't _do_ it.

Answer (score 13):

> A reason that I didn't see, because I don't try to answer questions that I'm reviewing.

This is actually one of the reasons I find reviewing immensely difficult (to the point I never did it much through the queues). I find that before I can judge whether a question ought to be closed, I usually need enough understanding to determine whether or not an answer is feasible or reasonable. Otherwise, it's far too easy to misconstrue the question and end up casting an incorrect vote. In other words, I *do* try to develop a rudimentary, intuitive answer to the question to determine whether a question should be closed, and I believe that approach to be the correct one. This is one reason I rarely cast votes for questions in technologies outside of my expertise; I often can't determine whether answering it is reasonable if I don't have some grasp of the technology.

Comment: I understand. Personnally, even if I already made lot of web dev, I didn't find the good answer for this audit: I was thinking about the `type="hidden"`. So even with competences in this subject, I will not find typo issue

Comment: The skip button is intended to handle cases where you're not sure what should be done.  Some bad questions are blatantly obvious ex "do my homework for me", "thousand line code dump", "it doesn't work without saying what 'work' means"; others as you've noted require deeper understanding of the platform in question.  For platforms you don't understand well enough to decide just skip and leave it to people who do know the subject well enough.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Sure. I even tried tag filters. But that doesn't eliminate the amount of effort that goes into evaluating most questions that end up in the review queue.